# find and replace notepad++ or dreamweaver

Tags: html, text-editor

there has to be a simple solution for this but I can not figure it out. Help.
I need to delete everything (in over 1000 html files) that is between

```
<body>
......
......
<table>
```

How do i do this please?

Comment: You need to learn how to use regular expressions in Notepad++. This might get you started... http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

In dreamweaver you can search and replace using regular expressions:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt2.html